# Find X such that 22 divides $11^{2n−1}+X^{3n+1}$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Need help on inductions, having a few issues.

Answer (score 1):

I take this to mean, find all positive integers $A$ such that $$A^{3n+1}+13^{2n-1}\equiv0\pmod{11}$$ for every positive integer $n$.  This is the same as $$A^{3n+1}\equiv-2^{2n-1}$$ for every positive inter $n$. Suppose this equation is true for some $n$.  When $n$ increases by $1$, the left-hand side is multiplied by $A^3$ and the right-hand side is multiplied by $4$, so we must have $$A^3\equiv4\pmod{11}$$  We find by trial that the only solution mod $11$ is $A\equiv5$.  We have to check $n=1$, and we find $5^4\equiv9\equiv-2\pmod{11}$, so the answer is all integers $$A\equiv5\pmod{11}$$

**EDIT**

There is one point in the argument that relies on the fact that $11$ is prime.  Do you see where I failed to mention that?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n=A^{3n+1} + 13^{2n−1}$. Then $x_{n+2}= a x_{n+1} + b x_n$, where $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ whose values are irrelevant; the important point is that they are integers.

Therefore, if $11$ divides $x_1$ and $x_2$, then $11$ divides $x_n$ for all $n$. Now,

- $11$ divides $x_1=A^4+13$ iff $A \equiv \pm 5 \bmod 11$.
- $11$ divides $x_2=A^7+13^3$ iff $A \equiv 5 \bmod 11$.

Bottom line: $A \equiv 5 \bmod 11$.